# Products on multi-store Magento installation will display for one website but not the other

Tags: magento-1, multistore, multicurrency, store-switcher

I have a Magento 1.9 store and we're trying to implement a multi store set up on it as we're in the UK and we want to cater for the US market too. I've installed the Mageworx Store & Currency Auto Switcher, and so far the extension works. If it detects a user from the USA, it switches the store to a different view.

But here lies the problem. If I'm viewing the site from the UK I have access to all the products like I should do. The site is the same as it was before we implemented the store auto switcher. Here's a screenshot of it in action.

[image]

However, when I switch to a US IP address, no products appear. Here's a screenshot to show what I mean:

[image]

Both screenshots are from the same product page.

I have reindexed the store multiple times, using the Admin panel and through the shell in the command line. I've cleared the cache in a similar fashion. All of the products are set to be visible on both sites too as well as the categories.

One interesting thing I have noted is that if I go to the product page directly when on the UK side I get the full product page (like normal), as seen here:

[image]

However, if I visit this product while using a US IP address (meaning the store should switch) I get the following screen:

[image]

So for whatever reason the moment products are viewed on the US side, the website does switch to the view/store it should switch to but the products aren't displayed.

It's an usual issue, and I can't seem to find any errors within the log files. I've re-indexed, cleared the cache, and made sure the categories and products are set to be enabled for both sites. I've even disabled and enabled products and categories and that hasn't made a difference.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

**EDIT:** From playing about, I've nailed the issue (I think) to the product image. I went in to the view file and started to tear out a lot of the code. When I removed this line of code, the products displayed:

```
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

With further hacking away at the code, it's this line that seems to be causing all my problems:

```
src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
```

Once I remove that, the products display but without the image displayed, just the contents of the `alt` field.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the output of the `error.log` on the server:

```
[Tue Aug 15 07:31:06 2017] [error] [client 194.74.148.204] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' in /var/www/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 44
[Tue Aug 15 07:31:16 2017] [error] [client 207.244.86.238] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' in /var/www/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 44, referer: http://www.website.com
[Tue Aug 15 07:31:20 2017] [error] [client 207.244.86.238] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' in /var/www/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 44, referer: http://www.website.com
[Tue Aug 15 07:31:48 2017] [error] [client 207.244.86.238] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' in /var/www/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 44, referer: http://www.website.com
[Tue Aug 15 07:32:03 2017] [error] [client 207.244.86.238] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99 - assumed '\xe2\x80\x99display_errors\xe2\x80\x99' in /var/www/website.com/public_html/index.php on line 44, referer: http://www.website.com
```

Comment: Why you does not contact the MageWorx support team?

Comment: I have, and they haven't answered.

Comment: Please, open the `error.log` (usually it is located at `/var/apache2/log/error.log`) of your server and update your question: add the latest magento-related errors.

Comment: Could you post your ticket-number (ID) in the MageWorx system? I'll try to hurry up them.

Comment: I've edited the question with the output of the error.log

Comment: @mickburkejnr 

Normally, we answer all support queries within 24 hours max. 

Could you please send us your ticket ID, so we could check why it's not been answered yet? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would rather it was sorted out here in public, because at least then the answer can be found without having to wait days for a response.

Comment: @mickburkejnr it is good to you check with @MageWorx about this issue because the code of this extension is not available. Or you can post the error by renaming `error/local.xml.sample`  to `error/local.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally cracked the issue.

After exhausting so many avenues with this issue, it turned out the server didn't have the PHP GD library installed. I'm not really sure why this would be a problem in a multi-store set up and not a problem on the whole, but since installing it the site is behaving like it should.